# How do I encode and decode PER-encoded data in Python?

Tags: python, asn.1

I need to be able to decode and encode [PER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packed_Encoding_Rules)-encoded octet strings using Python.  I found [PyASN1](http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/), but it doesn't include a PER codec.  Is there another solution out there?  How difficult would it be to write a PER codec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, I remember well, there is an incomplete implementation / support of PER encoding format in SNMPy .

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/snmpy/

Comment: All I can find is the snmpy_hex_to_binary() function in snmpymodule.c.  That may help.  I'll see.